# Angular2 - Sorting an array to a specific order

Tags: angular

Whats's a reusable and expandable way to sort an array to a specific order?

From the backend i get a list of items randomly ordered. The list has to be sorted in a specific order for the user to see. The sorting has to be done in the front-end. I can't touch the backend.

Example:

Item3, Item1, Item2 or Item1, Item3, Item2, ...

-> Sorted

Item1,
Item2,
Item3

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code:

```js
function sortIt(arr){
  return arr.sort((a,b) => a.replace(/[a-z]+/gi, '') - b.replace(/[a-z]+/gi, ''));
}

console.log(sortIt(['Item3', 'Item1', 'Item2']));
console.log(sortIt(['Item12', 'Item3', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item4']));
console.log(sortIt(['Item1', 'Item1', 'Item2']));
```

Comment: The items are purely hypothetically. I get environments from the back end each with their specific key.

Comment: @user2963570 It will work for all elements which ends with some number, because the sorting function depends on it.

Comment: Yes thats true but in my case I don't have any numbers. I get environments returned which hold a specific key ex: dev, acc, .... Based on that key I need to set the environment on the index it's supposed to be.

Comment: If you are looking for a universal sorting code that will work on every key, it will be a quite difficult task. But if you would give me an example of that key, I can adjust my code to fit your expectations.

Comment: keys are: dev, acc, prd

Comment: `['dev1', 'dev2']`? Try to demonstrate it to me somehow.

Comment: [{key: 'dev'},{key: 'acc'},{key: 'prd'}]

Comment: I don't really get your point. You want that `Environments` array to be sorted by these keys? So it will be like: `[{key: 'acc'}, {key: 'dev'}, {key: 'prd'}]`?

Answer (score 0):

Recently i posted answer to the similar question, see [gist](https://gist.github.com/kemsky/96b3201d0fa972a8cdecee39ea18a516), it can be used like this:

```
  [{key: 'dev'},{key: 'acc'},{key: 'prd'}].sort(compare<{key:string}>({property: 'key'}));
```